# How to select data and conditionally combine it in one query

Tags: sql

I have the following tables:

T1

```
V | H
--+--
a   q
s   w
d   e
f   r
```

T2

```
VH
--
 a
 w
 d
 e
```

And I need the following result:

```
V | H | RES
--+---+----
a   q    V
s   w    H
d   e    B
```

I.e., I need to select that rows from the T1 which `V` or `H` (or both) values exist in the T2 and additional column `RES` which value should be 'V' if the `T1.V` value is found in the T2, 'H' if the `T1.H` value is found in the T2, or 'B' if both of the `T1.V` and `T1.H` values are present in the T2 table.

I need the ANSI SQL query, without any specific DB-engine syntax.

Comment: So what have you attempted?

Comment: @OldProgrammer I tried to `union` several queries as well to `join` the tables and several combinations of these two points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `CASE WHEN` to achieve that

```
SELECT T1.*, 
CASE WHEN T1.V IN (SELECT VH FROM T2) AND T1.H IN (SELECT VH FROM T2) THEN 'B'
WHEN T1.V IN (SELECT VH FROM T2) THEN 'V'
WHEN T1.H IN (SELECT VH FROM T2) THEN 'H' ELSE 'N' END AS RES
FROM T1
WHERE RES <> 'N'
```

Answer (score 0):

I found one more way:

```
SELECT 'V' AS RES, T1.* FROM T1
WHERE T1.V IN (SELECT VH FROM T2) AND T1.H NOT IN (SELECT VH FROM T2)
UNION SELECT 'H', T1.* FROM T1
WHERE T1.V NOT IN (SELECT VH FROM T2) AND T1.H IN (SELECT VH FROM T2)
UNION SELECT 'B', T1.* FROM T1
WHERE T1.V IN (SELECT VH FROM T2) AND T1.H IN (SELECT VH FROM T2)
```